# Android : Widget 1*1 not adding up to screen

Tags: android, android-widget

I have created an android widget
 when i go to widget menu and select my created widget it shows , two widget **1*1** and **3*3**

when i dragged the widget to my home screen it places only **3*3** widget and **1*1** Widget cannot be placed , can any one suggest me the right solution what i am missing.

My widget contain only one icon and i want the widget to be **1*1**
here is my code :

**Manifest.xml**

```
  <receiver android:name=".Main3Activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/mywidget" />
    </receiver>
```

**xml/mywidget**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="172dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:minHeight="172dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main3">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**activity_main3**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:transitionGroup="true">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Widget"
    android:background="@drawable/widgeton"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google the minimun width and height for a block in the home screen should be

**70 × n − 30** for width and height now image is taking 1×1 screen size in home.

To work  for 1*1 i have updated the layout to:

**xml/mywidget**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="40dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/activity_main3">
</appwidget-provider>
```